# 'C:\MPIHello\bin\Debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using MPI;

class MPIHello
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
        {
            Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;
            if (comm.Rank == 0)
            {
                //Send its rank to the next neighbor
                comm.Send(comm.Rank, 1, 0);

                //Receive message 
                int msg = comm.Receive<int>(comm.Size, 0);

                Console.WriteLine("I am MPI process " + comm.Rank + " of " + comm.Size    + ", on my left is " + msg);
            }
            else
            {
                //Receive message
                int msg = comm.Receive<int>(comm.Rank - 1, 0);

                Console.WriteLine("I am MPI process " + comm.Rank + " of " + comm.Size + ", on my left is " + msg);

                //Send message to next neighbor
                comm.Send(comm.Rank, (comm.Rank + 1) % comm.Size, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the C# coding that I have done, but when I want to run it in the Command Prompt, this error comes out 'C:\MPIHello\bin\Debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file... May I know what is the problem?

Comment: How are you running it from the command line? That error likely doesn't have much to do with your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is a directory. Usually, the program is inside this directory. Can you give more info?

Comment: The correct answer right here. You are trying to launch a directory, not a file.

Comment: what the 'more info' you mean?